# What happened between Carter and Martouf?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In The Tok'ra, Sam and Martouf agree to wait together for Selmak to heal Jacob's cancer. Later, when Garshaw shows up and surprises them, they are clearly holding hands and jump away, embarrassed.

It was established in the episode that they were waiting for a rather long time - are we to believe they were only holding hands the entire time, or they actually go so far as having intercourse? It seems like this would not be appropriate with Samantha's father right there in the same room, so I have my doubts that they took it that far, but the way the scene is edited feels highly suggestive to me.

**Is there any information in the show (or additional materials) regarding the nature of Carter's relationship with Martouf?**

Comment: Her dad was in the room, dude.

Answer (score 4):

Only a close emotional relationship was revealed, which was prompted by Samantha being host to  Jolinar for a short time (Martouf's mate). An intimate relationship was never implied between Samantha and Martouf.

Source: [Martouf's Wikia page](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Martouf)